# lastest xcode 15.0.1 stuck installing to iphone (2) <-- displays "2" to right of status message on top bar

Tags: ios, xcode

All of a sudden, when I try to run my swift app on my iphone attached to my mac2, the xcode top bar displays:

"Installing my_app to iPhone (2)"

the (2) is a gray disk with a 2 in it.
When I click this (2), it pops down...
(rotating circle) Attaching to my app on iphone...
(rotating circle) Installing   yada yada

Comment: It happened sometimes. I think the solution is to unplug your phone and remove its pair on Xcode -> iOS DeviceSupport. Restart the phone, then plug it in to pair again. Hope it helps.

Comment: Happening to me too. Never known such a buggy product. Unpluging the dreaded pad thing seemed to sort that out.

Comment: This is happening almost daily since Xcode 15... very annoying...

Answer (score 1):

In my case something was stuck on the iPhone.

1. Restarted Xcode
2. Restarted the iPhone
3. Delete the app
4. Suddenly there's an empty app on the homescreen - restart iPhone again
5. Run app

Answer (score 0):

I got it going.

Here's all I did...

Restarted xcode

Disconnect iPhone from your Mac.
On your iPhone, go to Settings > Developer > Clear Trusted Computers.
Uninstall my application.
Reconnect iPhone to Mac.
In Xcode, go to Window > Devices & Simulators. You should see your device in the left sidebar.

Restart mac & iphone

After all this, my app ran on iphone.